# How to design a flutter timeline widget with fixed times and variable events

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a vertical timeline in flutter but I've hit a roadblock on how to design the timeline and event system. The image below is what I have and how I want it to show. The yellow container is the event, events can be on either side and overlap other events. Currently it's three rows inside a column, with the sides expanded and middle fixed width. Each dot is its own widget with a datetime associated with it.

Now my issue is, how can I make it so that the events line up with the center numbers based on datetime?
I'm currently using **positioned** on the event with top, but I have no way of getting the distance from the top of the center widgets.

[image: Timeline with event]

**main build**

```
child: Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  children: <Widget>[
    IntrinsicHeight(
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildLeftCol(),
          _buildCenterCol(CustomTime().times),
          _buildRightCol(12)
        ],
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

**_buildLeftCol**

```
Widget _buildLeftCol() {
  return Expanded(
    child: Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildEventItem(DateTime.now()),
        ],
      )
    ),
  );
}
```

**_buildEventItem**

```
Widget _buildEventItem(DateTime time) {

  var index = CustomTime().getIndexOf(time);
  var position = 41.0 * index;

  return Positioned(
    left: 160,
    top: position,
    child: Container(
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      color: Colors.yellow,
      child: Text("data")
    ),
  );
}
```

```
Widget _buildCenterCol(List<DateTime> list) {
  return Column(children: list.map((time) => timeItem(time)).toList());
}

Widget timeItem(DateTime time) {
  if(time.minute != 00) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:8.0, bottom: 8.0),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9.0),
        child: Container(
          height: 18,
          width: 18,
          color: Color(0xFF0288D1),
        ),
      ),
    );
  } else {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0),
      child: Container(
        height: 64,
        width: 64,
        color: Color(0xFF00305A),
        child: Center(child: Text(DateFormat('HH').format(time), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 32.0),))
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: well your logic is right , you need to work with stack and positioned and you did so... can you share the code of the stack

Comment: What happens if 16 has data too? And what if the data is _huge_?

Comment: Added some code of the widgets, it might be a bit spaghetti because I've been struggling with this issue for a few days now on and off with lots of code edits. @RémiRousselet if data overlaps it gets pushed to the other side, if that overlaps as well it gets pushed to the side. There won't be a lot of data. Since events are sequential. Data will be an image/pictogram and a title. Eat dinner for instance.

Comment: nah bro you made a mistake 
if you want to play with the widgets and place them wherever you want (on top of each other for example ) you need to make them all part of the stack widget
so those blue and dark blue dots should also be inside of stack

Comment: @othman That's how I had it initially, the issue isn't as much stacking as knowing where the position of each "dot widget" is. At first I tried having a row in each column for each timeItem. Then used stack for the events. This worked with positioning, but the event widget would go behind the row below it.

Comment: @amunds "the event widget would go behind the row below it" each one need specific positioned(top and left) and if you want a widget to apear in front just make it the last one to call ,, so if with the same positioned you call : _buildLeftCol(),
          _buildCenterCol(),
          _buildRightCol() the one that will apear is _buildRightCol and so on

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [timeline_tile](https://github.com/JHBitencourt/timeline_tile) package released recently. Currently it does not provide dotted lines, but you can easily achieve what you desire with its tiles, for example:

```
TimelineTile(
  alignment: TimelineAlign.center,
  rightChild: Container(
    constraints: const BoxConstraints(
      minHeight: 120,
    ),
    color: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
  ),
  leftChild: Container(
    color: Colors.amberAccent,
  ),
);
```

If aligned `center` os `manual` you can have children on both sides.

Also, the [beautiful_timelines](https://github.com/JHBitencourt/beautiful_timelines) repository contains some examples built with this package.